# Asking for websites

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

In the math Stack Exchange can I ask for websites relating to math that others might suggest? For example, I was thinking about asking this question, but was hesitant:

> Next semester I'm taking calculus at college and I was looking for websites that have quizzes/test for things like trigonometry, trig formulas, pre-calculus, calculus readiness, etc. so I can get ready this summer. I found the "MU Math Tests Homepage"
>
> http://mathonline.missouri.edu/mucgi-bin/munew.cgi?variable=
>
> But the questions aren't that challenging. Any ideas? (other than doing problems from library books)

I feel it wouldn't be appropriate but I'd like to ask this specific question. Any chances?

Comment: Looks good to me. Could be tagged *online-resources*, *trigonometry*,  and *algebra-precalculus*.

Comment: You might first look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90/online-resources-for-learning-mathematics and maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80202/what-does-khan-academy-have-to-offer-depth-rigor